# Rails -- Using CSS3's @font-face

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, font-face

In my `global.css` file which is loaded by `application.html.erb`, I have the following lines:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  src: url(/lib/fonts/MyFont-AH.ttf) format("truetype"); /* For IE */
  src: local("MyFont-AH"), url(/lib/fonts/MyFont-AH.ttf) format("truetype"); /* Non-IE */ 

}
```

And then elsewhere I have

```
h1 {
  font-family: myfont, helvetica, arial;
}
```

When I booted up the server h1 was using the Helvetica font, and I got the error in my log `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lib/fonts/MyFont-AH.ttf"):`.  I figured that this meant I would need to edit my routes file, so I went and added the line `get "/lib/fonts/MyFont-AH.ttf"`, but then when I reloaded the page I got the error `missing :controller` because there is no controller tied to this action.  When I created a controller and matched the get request to it, it then wanted a template.  It seems that it wants me to have a controller / action set up like most other get requests, so I'm not quite sure what to do here.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I upgraded to Rails 3.2 and am using the Asset Pipeline (from Rails 3.1+), and I placed the fonts I wanted to display in `vendor/assets/fonts`.  Then I added the following line to my `application.rb` file: `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/fonts"`.  Finally in my CSS file I used the format:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  src: url("/assets/myfont.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For IE */
  src: local("myfont"), url("/assets/myfont.ttf") format("truetype"); /* For non-IE */
}
```

I think a part of the original problem might have been that my files were stored with the extension `.TTF` rather than `.ttf` but I'm not sure.  All I know is it's working now.

Comment: I had to just reference myfont.ttf instead of /assets/myfont.ttf, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this myself but I'd have thought that your fonts should be stored in either the public or the assets directory (depending on which version of rails you're using).  Lib isn't a directory that's make available for users to download from (unless you're using some sort of clever gem that is meant to handle this for you?).

On pre Rails 3.1 I'd put my fonts in

```
public/fonts
```

And then reference them with

```
url(../fonts/MyFont-AH.ttf)
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: as of today 3.2 - when I asked the question I was using 3.0.7, but now that I changed over I am going to see if I can get it working with the Asset Pipeline.  If you know how to get it working using assets please let me know!

Comment: In that case I think you would put it in app/assets/fonts and then when you reference it in your CSS insteaed of url you should use `font-url('MyFont-AH.ttf')` or `asset-url('MyFont-AH.ttf', font)`.